# Module values in F# don't get initialized. Why?

Tags: f#, module

I got a strange behavior when I used F#.
When I use let binding in a module, and if the value is created from a constructor, then it's uninitialized when used outside. (I used it from C# using ModuleName.s2 or ModuleName.f())

```
//in a module
let s1 = "1" //normal
let s2 = new String('i', 5) //null

let f () =
    s2.Equals("something") //Exception
```

Is this a normal behavior? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
For the purpose of debugging, I choose to compile it as an executable. This may be the problem as other people pointed out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your F# assembly a library or an executable?

Comment: @kvb, I get this behavior only when compiling as an executable.

Comment: @kvb, executable. I may change it to library later but executable seems to be better for debugging.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In an F# library, modules are initialized via static constructors which ensure that initialization occurs prior to any of the module's values being used.  By contrast, in an F# executable, this initialization is performed in the application's entry point.  This means that if another assembly references the F# application (regardless of the language the other application is written in), the initialization code won't be run.

**UPDATE**

Brian pointed me to [this part of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597617), which indicates that this is the expected behavior.

It looks like one workaround would be to provide an explicit entry point, like this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    0
```

<strike>You can then call this main method from your C# app to ensure that the module's contents are properly initialized.</strike>

**UPDATE 2**

I was misreading the spec - you do not need to actually call the explicit entry point from the referencing assembly.  Its mere presence will cause the initialization to occur correctly.

Comment: @LLS - Happy to help.  I've made a small correction - you don't need to call the entry point from the other assembly.

Comment: This is why I love Stack Overflow, +1 for this very useful answer!  Was wondering why everything was null.  Figured it had to something to do with the parts of the module not being initialized correctly.

Comment: F# 3.1 - I have an explicit entry point but still run into this problem. (I have a unit test project that references the .exe.. unit tests fail because things are null that shouldn't be null.)

Comment: @stmax - You'll probably get better advice if you open a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: @kvb - after some debugging i found out that my problem was caused by something completely different / only the symptoms were exactly the same. so F#'s doing everything right and your suggestion with the entry point works! (PS.: i verified that it still works with .net 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 and F# 3.0 and 3.1)

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, `SomeModule.s2` is implemented as a (read-only) property that returns the value of the unspeakable static field `<StartupCode$FS>.$Program.s2@9`. If you compile as an application, that field is initialized in the main method. When used from your C# code, this method is not called, so the field is not initialized.

If you compile as a library, the code is the same, except the field is initialized in the static constructor of the `$Program` class, so it should work when used from C#.

The reason `s1` always works is optimization: the F# compiler understands it's a constant and implements `f()` as `"1".Equals("something")`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that there is a difference between library and executable.