# Can't access a partially applied function with in a class

Tags: f#, ncrunch

I'm extremely new to F# and was playing around with the stack calculator on the [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/stack-based-calculator/) (excellent site). I was trying to figure out how to have a test project and class. I have a test class with this method:

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FSharpDoodles.MainProgram

[<TestFixture>]
type ProgramTests()=

    [<Test>]
    member self.FirstTest()=
        // Create some stacks
        let EMPTY = StackContents []
        let try1 = push 1.0 EMPTY      // OK
        let try2_partial = push 1.0    // OK
        let try2 = try2_partial EMPTY  // OK - does same as ONE below
        let stackWith1 = ONE EMPTY     // FAILS: ONE is null
        ()
```

The code it is testing is thus:

```
module FSharpDoodles.MainProgram 

type Stack = StackContents of float list

let push x (StackContents contents) =
    StackContents ( x::contents )

let ONE = push 1.0
```

So, if I'm calling a function and getting a value (call to push), it works. And if I create a partially applied function in the class (try2_partial), that works. But when I'm referencing ONE, which is returning a partially applied function, ONE is null.

Why is that?

**The Rest of The Story**

I'm using NCrunch as my test runner. It is entirely possible that it is causing a problem.

**Edit**

As suggested by John, I tried this in FSI and get the same issue. Below is the progressive application of the same test code:

```
open FSharpDoodles.MainProgram
let EMPTY = StackContents [];;


val EMPTY : FSharpDoodles.MainProgram.Stack = StackContents []

> let try1 = push 1.0 EMPTY;;


val try1 : Stack = StackContents [1.0]

> let try2_partial = push 1.0;;


val try2_partial : (Stack -> Stack)

> let try2 = try2_partial EMPTY;;


val try2 : Stack = StackContents [1.0]

> let stackWith1 = ONE EMPTY;;
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0006>.$FSI_0006.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

I made a reference to the SUT for FSI under **Tools|Options** -> *F# Interactive*, *F# Interactive options*. I used *-r* and referenced the assembly in debug\bin.

As I mentioned, I very new to this F# stuff and I might be making some very rookie mistake related to how I'm putting together either of the modules.

**Update 2**

Based on John's comment, I tried moving the code from an *.exe* to a *.dll* (library).  It worked fine. So, the issue is related to referencing the **.exe**. So the question now evolves into why this makes a difference (exe vs dll)?

Comment: My guess would be the test runner not calling the module setup correctly, leaving the `ONE` uninitialised.  You can test this by running the code in FSI.  Maybe try a different test runner?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I've just executed this test with TestDriven.NET, and it works as expected; stepping through with the debugger shows that both `stackWith1` and `ONE` are proper values (and not null).

Comment: What do you get in fsi when you just try to evaluate `ONE`?

Comment: Are you compiling the assembly containing `ONE` as an exe or a dll?

Comment: As an exe (console app).

Comment: Same error when I try to evaluate ONE: let s = ONE 1.0 StackContents [];; The value or constructor 'ONE' is not defined

Comment: OK, this is related to it being an EXE. I moved code to a library and it worked fine.  Thanks to John for asking the right question. :D If somebody knows why this makes a difference (exe vs dll) or has a link to a reference about this, post it as the answer.

Comment: Perhaps this covers it?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6630262/82959

Comment: Didn't see the comment replies earlier but the difference is that when the code is compiled as an exe, F#, inserts some initialization code that runs early.  When you reference the exe, this code doesn't run.  Compiling as a dll fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is that I was referencing an EXE and not a DLL. Same code in a DLL works fine.  Thanks to [John Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124259/john-palmer) question for getting me to investigate that angle and then for providing the explanation (see the comments).