# How to build integrations tests for a Saturn app

Tags: f#, saturn-framework

I'm trying to build some integration tests for a small API I've built using the [Saturn framework](https://saturnframework.org/docs/).

The API is built with the usual `Saturn` computation expressions such as `application`, `controller`, `router` etc.

But in order to build integration tests I need to replace the `application` computation expression (ce) and hand craft a `WebHostBuilder`.

My `application` ce looks like this:

```
module Server 

let app =
    application {
        url ("http://0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + "/")
        use_router apiRouter
        memory_cache
        service_config configureSerialization
        use_gzip
        use_config (fun _ ->
            System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Location
                                                   |> Path.GetDirectoryName
            let configurationRoot =
                ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
                    .Build()
            let appConfig = FsConfig.AppConfig(configurationRoot)

            let dbPath =
                match appConfig.Get<AppSettings>() with
                | Ok settings when settings.DbConfig.Database.Contains(":memory:") -> settings.DbConfig.Database
                | Ok settings -> Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, settings.DbConfig.Database)
                | Error _ -> failwithf "Invalid database path"
            { connectionString = dbPath |> sprintf "DataSource=%s;Version=3" })
    }
```

With a `router` and on one of the `controllers`...

```
let cartController =
    controller {
        create createCartAction
        show getCartAction
        delete deleteCartAction
        subController "/items" cartItemsController
    }

let apiRouter =
    router {
        not_found_handler (setStatusCode 404 >=> text "Not found")
        pipe_through apiPipeline
        forward "/cart" cartController
    }
```

The code above is in my API project, the code with integration test below is in a second project. The latter has a project reference to the former.

```
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseGiraffe(Server.apiRouter) \\<-- The problem is here. Server.apiRouter is null!

let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddGiraffe() |> ignore

let builder = WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot) 
                .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
                .ConfigureServices(configureServices)

let testServer = new TestServer(builder)

let client = testServer.CreateClient()

let! response = client.GetAsync "/"

test <@ HttpStatusCode.OK = response.StatusCode @>
```

When the test is run it fails with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'A suitable constructor for type 'Giraffe.Middleware+GiraffeMiddleware' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.'
```

The problem appears to be with the line `app.UseGiraffe(Server.apiRouter)`. `apiRouter` is defined in the `Server` module of the API project - but when this code runs in the test project `Server.apiRouter` is `null`.

If however I move the test code into the same project as the `API` - the test works perfectly.

Why would the `apiRouter` computation expression be `null` if called from the test project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was nothing to do with `Saturn` at all. It's all to do with  the way that `F#` initiates `modules`. [The answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629891/module-values-in-f-dont-get-initialized-why)

As suggested in the referenced post. I simply added an `[<EntryPoint>]` function and everything worked as expected.