# Do aggressive F# compiler optimizations only occur on referenced dependencies + release configuration?

Tags: .net-core, f#, compiler-optimization

I faced something a little bit unexpected the other day in F# (+ .NET Core 3.1) about a `let` binding initialization (variable) which was not always occurring depending on which configuration the program compiler: debug or release.

Ok the problem went something along those lines (I purposefully simplified the code, and the behaviour can still be reproduced), I created a project that was a console one with a single file, below:

`Program.fs`:

```ml
open System
open ClassLibrary1
open Flurl.Http


[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Console =

    let private init =
        printfn "Console: A"
        FlurlHttp.Configure(fun settings ->
            printfn "Console: B"
            settings.AfterCall <- Unchecked.defaultof<Action<FlurlCall>>)

    let doStuff () =
        init
        printfn "Console: C"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    Console.doStuff()
    Library.doStuff()
    0
```

The `ClassLibrary1` namespace is actually a library project referenced to the console project.

That library project is also made of a single file:

`Library.fs`:

```ml
namespace ClassLibrary1

open System
open Flurl.Http


[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Library =

    let private init =
        printfn "Library: A"
        FlurlHttp.Configure(fun settings ->
            printfn "Library: B"
            settings.AfterCall <- Unchecked.defaultof<Action<FlurlCall>>)

    let doStuff () =
        init
        printfn "Library: C"
```

The difference when running the console project

Release output:

```
Console: A
Console: B
Console: C
Library: C
```

Debug output:

```
Console: A
Console: B
Console: C
Library: A
Library: B
Library: C
```

That was a bit disturbing, my colleague and I spent a fair amount of time trying to figure out what was going on.

So I would just like to confirm the compiler optimization rules in this context.

My understanding atm is:

- Executing project (the console one in my example above) does initialize the variable regardless of the configuration.
- Dependencies (the library project in my example) do initialize the variable only with a debug configuration.

I would like to know if my understanding is correct or no.

---

[EDIT]

Bent Tranberg suggested my post to be a duplicated of: [Module values in F# don't get initialized. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629891/module-values-in-f-dont-get-initialized-why)

So I checked the answers given in that post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630262/4636721
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630264/4636721

> Brian pointed me to [this part of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597617), which indicates that this is the expected behavior.
>
> It looks like one workaround would be to provide an explicit entry point, like this:
>
> ```ml
> [<EntryPoint>]
> let main _ =
>     0
> ```

So I did add an entry point in the library project

`Library.fs`

```
module ClassLibrary1

open System

open Flurl.Http


[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Library =
    let private init =
        printfn "Library: A"
        FlurlHttp.Configure(fun settings ->
            printfn "Library: B"
            settings.AfterCall <- Unchecked.defaultof<Action<FlurlCall>>)

    let doStuff () =
        init
        printfn "Library: C"


[<EntryPoint>]
let callMe _ =
    Library.doStuff ()
    0
```

and changed the executable program as follows:

```ml
open System

open ClassLibrary1
open Flurl.Http


[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Console =
    let private init =
        printfn "Console: A"
        FlurlHttp.Configure(fun settings ->
            printfn "Console: B"
            settings.AfterCall <- Unchecked.defaultof<Action<FlurlCall>>)

    let doStuff () =
        init
        printfn "Console: C"


[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    Console.doStuff()
    callMe [||] |> ignore
    0
```

And same thing happened, just as before.

I even changed the Library project type to an executable project and nothing has changed either...

Comment: That's the behavior I've always seen - there's a difference, not sure why. But in this particular case, why would you expect side effects not to be optimized away? Doing ´init´ is not actually doing anything. If you turn the ´init´'s into functions, then not only will they be called, but they'll be called inside ´main´, and not before. Just be sure to do the configuration stuff at first call only. Calling library stuff like ´FlurlHttp.Configure´ before ´main´ is the kind of thing I think of as hazardous.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629891/module-values-in-f-dont-get-initialized-why).

Comment: Yea it's a related problem, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Tbs, the answer given in that thread doesn't really work =|

Comment: A side note: A comment in that other Q mentioned that calling 'callMe' wasn't actually needed. It was sufficient that the 'EntryPoint' attribute was present. Not that I think this helps here anyway.

Comment: Yup, but I tried both...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one took some digging. This is the result of two different issues:

**Startup code**

This is because of how `fsc` chooses to generate the IL for modules. All the initialization code for a module [is bundled into a separate class](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/596f3d73f7fec4d9cae2b273b92c16206909bf52/src/fsharp/IlxGen.fs#L6674) in the `StartupCode$` namespace.

So the static constructor for the module actually [exists in a another class](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/596f3d73f7fec4d9cae2b273b92c16206909bf52/src/fsharp/IlxGen.fs#L340) named `<StartupCode$Assembly>.$ClassLibrary1`. Perhaps you can begin to see the problem with this - if this class is never referenced, the static constructor will never run.

**Aggressive optimizations**

In `Release` mode, F# will aggressively inline short methods, literals, and will *ignore* property accesses whose value is thrown away.

```
module Library =
    let private init =
        printfn "In init"
        0

    let doStuff () =
        init |> ignore //<-- will be thrown away
        printfn "%s" "doStuff"
```

To be more clear, this is what `init` looks like:

```
 static class ClassLibrary1 {    
    static Unit init { get { return <StartupCode$Assembly>.$ClassLibrary1.init; } }
 }
```

So without that property access referencing that field on the startup class, there's no part of the startup code class being used in the module, hence the static constructor won't run.

```
module Library =
    let private init =
        printfn "In init"
        0

    let doStuff () =
        init |> printfn "%d" // init is accessed
        printfn "%s" "doStuff"
```

The above code works because `init` can't be thrown away.
Finally, to demonstrate that any field or property access will do, we write up an example which ensures a property access - the mutable will prevent any optimizations.

```
module Library =
    let mutable str = "Anything will do"

    let private init =
        printfn "In init"        

    let doStuff () =        
        printfn "%s" str
```

You can see that the init code will still run.

Comment: thanks a ton!!! I was reading the F# specs and tried to wrap my head around them, also when I was using SharpLab to check the IL code or C# eq code in both configurations, I couldn't see any difference between (but the thing is that SharpLab work on a single file so it cant reflect the issues on multiple projects + dependencies).

Comment: Btw, as a rule of thumb, we decided to always have explicit functions for initialization stuff, or actual static class ctors under some circumstances.

Comment: Yea, it makes sense to make things more explicit